# Image link not clickable when i use col-sm-12 bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a site which uses the twiter bootstrap 3 framework.
When i make a row, with col-sm-12 that has a image inside that has a link, then the image link dosn't work.

Example:
http://bootply.com/106628

Comment: It's `href=""` not `src=""`. `<a>` tags without an `href` attribute are not clickable by default

Answer (score 3):

Your  element is wrong... instead of

```
<a src="http://www.example.com/thing">
```

It should be

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/thing">
```

Note that **src** has been changed to **href**